# List of sets and default dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to Python so I apologize if this a simple questions. However, I would appreciate the help. When I pass my function I am getting unhashable type: 'set' and I am not sure why.

I have data which is a list of sets:

```
listsets = ({'fruit', 'margarine', 'soups', 'bread'}, {'coffee', 'fruit', 'yogurt'},…
```

My goal is to find pair item count in each set like below:

```
('fruit', 'bread'): 24, ('fruit', 'margarine'): 78, …
```

I am using combinations function and default dict as follows:

```
counts = defaultdict(int)  
def paircounts (counts, list):  
    for a, b in combinations(list,2):  
        counts[(a, b)] +=1
        counts[(b, a)] +=1

paircounts(counts, listsets)
```

> Error - unhashable type: 'set'

I also tried to use frozenset on my listsets (not set) and got a Memory error (so I don't think I am supposed to be using it for my assignment)

NOTE: before I had a string of text which I converted to list of strings and then to list of sets (that is my listsets).

I also have tried converting to tuples and it gave me an memory error as well. I am not sure if I might be converting it wrong. I did the following: `[tuple(elem) for elem in listsets]`

Comment: A set cannot be a dictionary key because it's _mutable_. But it looks like you want _tuple_ keys? That would be possible because tuples are _immutable_ but I'm not sure where the numerical values are coming from? `+= 1` on its own doesn't look like it would produce your expected output without more info.

Comment: The memory error is more complex to address. You haven't given an indication of the size of your problem.

Comment: Note also that `for a, b in combinations(list,2):` `a` and `b` are sets so you finding combinations of sets not combinations of elements of the set.

Comment: the numerical values are coming from counting the sets. I would like to numerates all item-pairs ('fruit', 'bread' would be 1 and if there is another set like that in the list then it would add 1 to make it 2)

Comment: I have tried converting to tuples and it gave me an memory error as well. I am not sure if I might be converting it wrong. I did the following: [tuple(elem) for elem in listsets]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem more efficiently with the `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations, chain
Counter(chain.from_iterable(combinations(l,2) for l in listsets))
#Counter({('soups', 'fruit'): 1, ('soups', 'bread'): 1, 
#         ('soups', 'margarine'): 1, ('fruit', 'bread'): 1, 
#         ('fruit', 'margarine'): 1, ('bread', 'margarine'): 1, 
#         ('yogurt', 'fruit'): 1, ('yogurt', 'coffee'): 1, ('fruit', 'coffee'): 1})
```

For any practical purpose, a `Counter` behaves like a `dict`.